# Would anyone happen to know what model this HED wheel is?

Tags: wheels, identify-this-bike, disc-wheel

I have come upon this HED rear disc wheel and want to do a quick cost evaluation, and identify the model year ideally. Any help would be appreciated! [image: HED Disc Wheel]

Comment: A quick search leads me to think it "may" be 8/9/10 speed compatible, which is a broad time span to narrow down (1990s-2015?).  You might contact the company to see.  They may be able to provide you with a clue to search for that would narrow it down.  I could not find an exact copy of the images you show, but similar ones.